# How can I start the child process with the specific access rights

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

How can I start the child process from the current application via WinAPI with the specific access rights (in my case `PROCESS_VM_OPERATION | PROCESS_VM_READ | PROCESS_VM_WRITE | PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION`)? 
I don't see any related parameters in case of `CreateProcess` and `ShellExecuteEx` functions. Or should I create process as usual and then use the function `OpenProcess` with the required flags?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think they should be passed as security attributes to CreateProcess. [Check MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684880%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: The access rights apply to the handle, not the process as a whole. The handle you get back from CreateProcess has full access to the child.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your parent process to have a particular access to new process handle, it will be probably easier to use OpenProcess()

```
HANDLE hProcess = ::OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, FALSE, pid);
if (!hProcess)
    return ::GetLastError();

// get process token
HANDLE hToken = NULL;
if (::OpenProcessToken(hProcess, TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken))
    ...
```